# Maya API to get/read expression of Node attribute

Tags: api, maya, maya-api

I'm writing custom maya export plugin and I need to read expression of Node's attribute. But when I tried to use Maya api "MFnExpression" to read expression I get always

> (kInvalidParameter): Object is incompatible with this method

Below is code:

```
        MFnExpression fnExpression(dagPath.node(), &status);
        cout << endl << dagPath.fullPathName() << " status " << status << endl;
```

Any reference code could be helpful.

Comment: I suppose the mObject argument of the MFnExpression() has to be the mobject of the expression node, is this the case in your code?